# Constructible set in Gieseker's 'Lectures on Moduli of Curves'

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading Gieseker's [*Lectures on Moduli of Curves*](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr69.pdf), and I have a question concerning a statement made on page 69.

We are given a family $p : Z \to U$ of connected curves of genus $g\geq 2$ and degree $d$ in $\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}\PP^N$ (verifying a special semi-stability condition). For a geometric point $h\in U$, let $X_h$ be the fibre of $p$ over $h$. Moreover, let $L_h$ be the restriction of $O_{\PP^N}(1)$ to $X_h$, and $\omega_{X_h}$ be the dualizing sheaf of $X_h$.

Gieseker states on page 69, at the beginning of chapter 2:

> It is easily seen that the set $U_C = \{ h\in U \mid L_h \simeq \omega_{X_h}^n \}$ is constructable.

I don't know how to prove it... It's not easy for me... Please let me know why the set $U_C$ is constructible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not too hard to check that the property defining $U_C$ is a constructible property (following EGA $IV_3$ definition 9.2.1).  Then you can use *ibid.* Proposition 9.2.3.